# Airflow Variable Usage in DAG file

Tags: python, global-variables, airflow

I have a short DAG where I need to get the variable stored in Airflow (Airflow -> Admin -> variables). But, when we use as a template I'm getting below error.
Sample code and error shown below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def display_variable():
    my_var = Variable.get("my_var")
    print('variable' + my_var)
    return my_var

def display_variable1():
    my_var = {{ var.value.my_var }}
    print('variable' + my_var)
    return my_var

dag = DAG(dag_id="variable_dag", start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(14),
    schedule_interval='@daily')

task = PythonOperator(task_id='display_variable', python_callable=display_variable, dag=dag)

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='display_variable1', python_callable=display_variable1, dag=dag)

task >> task1
```

Here the usage to get the value of a variable using:

```
Variable.ger("my_var") --> is working
```

But, I'm getting an error using the other way:

```
{{ var.value.my_var }}
```

Error:

```
  File "/home/airflow_home/dags/variable_dag.py", line 12, in display_variable1
    my_var = {{ var.value.my_var }}
    NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `display_variable` functions run Python code, so `Variable.get()` works as intended. The `{{ ... }}` syntax is used for templated strings. Some arguments of most Airflow operators support templated strings, which can be given as `"{{ expression to be evaluated at runtime }}"`. Look up [Jinja templating](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) for more information. Before a task is executed, templated strings are evaluated. For example:

```py
BashOperator(
    task_id="print_now",
    bash_command="echo It is currently {{ macros.datetime.now() }}",
)
```

Airflow evaluates the `bash_command` just before executing it, and as a result the `bash_command` will hold e.g. "Today is Wednesday".

However, running `{{ ... }}` as if it were Python code would actually try to create a nested set:

```
{{ variable }}
^^
|└── inner set
|
outer set
```

Since sets are not hashable in Python, this will never evaluate, even if the statement inside is valid.

Additional resources:

- https://www.astronomer.io/guides/templating
- The `template_fields` attribute on each operator defines which attributes are template-able, see docs for your operator to see the value of `template_fields`: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.PythonOperator.template_fields

Comment: I rather confused with your answer. Do you mean to say that the templating {{ ... }} will not work in **pythonOperator** ??

Comment: That's correct, since the function called by the PythonOperator executes Python code. Only strings are templated at runtime, Python code is not. Therefore, to fetch a variable using Python code you must use `Variable.get("my_var")`.

To be exact, the PythonOperator does support templating (all operators do), but only on certain attributes. Check `template_fields` on your operator of choice to see which attributes can take templated strings.